# LinqToXML, breaking when Node doesn't exist. How do I check for existence?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(inputXML);
```

this bombs out when "amount" node is not present. How can I check for existence prior to evaluating?

```
 decimal amt;
 var amount = doc.Descendants("amount").SingleOrDefault().Value;
 bool amountValid = decimal.TryParse(amount, out amt);
```

I need to make sure "amount" is available prior to evaluating.

Can anyone help?

Thanks All,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var amountElement = doc.Descendants("amount").SingleOrDefault();

if (amountElement != null)
{
    decimal amt;
    bool amountValid = decimal.TryParse(amountElement.Value, out amt);

    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

XElement provides [explicit casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit.aspx) for most value types, including `Nullable<Decimal>`:

```
var amt = (decimal?)doc.Descendants("amount").SingleOrDefault();
```

From there you can check if `amt` is `null` or use its `HasValue` property.

**Update:** It's worth pointing out that the cast will throw a `FormatException` if the value is not a `Decimal`. If you still want to use `TryParse`, you can keep the code simple with a `string` cast:

```
decimal amt;
var amount = (string)doc.Descendants("amount").SingleOrDefault();
bool amountValid = decimal.TryParse(amount, out amt);
```

Internally, the string cast is implemented like Ben's sample, returning either `null` or `element.Value`.

Comment: +1: Didn't know that--great tip! I'm constantly impressed with how well-thought-out XLinq is.